# SSML - Is it possible to remove automatic break pauses?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, ssml, speechsynthesizer

I'm trying to remove the automatic breaks added by the synthesis processor, to create speech files without any "linguistic pauses".

I'm using Microsoft's speech synthesis engine with the `SpeechSynthesizer` class in C#.

This is the output I get with "This is an example why do automatic breaks occur?" wrapped in `<speak>` tags with `SpeechSynthesizer`:

https://clyp.it/4nofhh3n

This is the output I want (achieved by using [Oddcast's TTS Demo](https://ttsdemo.com/)):

https://clyp.it/m55wt14u

I've read through [w3.org's SSML documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/) several times which in point [3.2.3 - break element](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#edef_break), note the following:

`If the element is not present between tokens, the synthesis processor is expected to automatically determine a break based on the linguistic context. In practice, the break element is most often used to override the typical automatic behavior of a synthesis processor.`

This is how my voice is currently behaving. I want to somehow override/turn off this functionality, and have the speech be completely uninterrupted. I have tried putting a `<break>` element with attributes `strength="none"` and `time="0ms"` between the words where this automatic break occurs like they write above to override it, and all kinds of different things such as wrapping the whole text string in `<s>` tags etc, to no avail.

I also can't just remove the breaks in post processing, since the voice has a different tone on the words spoken, when the automatic breaks are added.

I have read through several different SSML documentations which, while often worded a bit differently compared to the w3 docs, don't explain how to concretely override the automatic breaks, which is my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my [experimenting with SpeechSynthesizer](https://gist.github.com/lselden/cde51ca2debdd7c7c16ea4abf621f8d5) if you put a break of 50ms at the end then it will respect it - if it's less then it'll be ignored.
However, it will always treat `<speak>` wrapped content as its own clause, so will speak it as if it's a sentence/clause, rather than carrying the prosody like the 2nd example. You need to send all your text in a single `<speak>` element (and voice) to have it treated as a single linguistic utterance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the example above I'm wrapping all the text in `<voice>` tags wrapped in a single `<speak>` tag, which still creates breaks mid-sentence. I'm using an externally downloaded voice commonly called "Daniel UK" - std Microsoft voices don't cause this break. The hacky way I solved the it was by making a list of every word that caused the break to occur (conjuctions), and with a regex command replacing the space (where the break would be) with a dash. The result is almost equivalent to how it sounds with the demo I linked above. Still don't know how to do it "properly".

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that behavior too. The dash is a good idea. The only way I think you could get it to work as a linguistic utterance is to render the whole sentence for each voice, then use `<mark>`s as guides on where to cut up the resulting audio files. Not an ideal solution, for sure.

Comment: Yep, the `<mark>` idea could potentially work, but since the inflection/tone of the words spoken at the end of a sentence/clause is different than if it would've been said without pause, this would lead to very inconcistent speech tone-wise. I think the dashes will have to do for now!